# How to add material toolbar in angular application?

Tags: material-design

I tried to import MatToolbar but it is not working

`import { MatToolbar } from '@angular/material/toolbar';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use need to import MatToolbarModule

```
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
```